# Interview Algorithm Query

Tags: c++, algorithm, pseudocode

> Given constant integers x and t, write a function that takes no
>   argument and returns true if the function has been called x number of
>   times in last t secs.

This is my pseudocode/C++ implementation for a possible algorithm, but I'm not sure if it's correct/efficient:

```
const int x;
const int t;
vector<long> v;
boolean countNumberOfTimesBeenCalled(){
    int numberOfCallsInLastTSeconds=0;
    v.push_back(System.currentTimeInMillis());
    for(int x=0; x<v.size();x++){
        if((v.at(x)>=(System.currentTimeInMillis()-1000*t))&&(v.at(x)<=System.currentTimeInMillis())
            numberOfCallsInLastTSeconds++;
    }
    if(numberOfCallsInLastTSeconds==x)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Can anyone suggest alternatives?

Comment: To summarize, you are timestamping each call and then checking how many calls have been performed as of the last `t` seconds by scanning through the vector? EDIT: Your two System class calls might return different times.  Why not call it once and store that value before continuing?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `size` and `capacity`?

Comment: if (something) then true else false is a good newbie indicator :) I don’t mean to offend

Comment: @qdii It is an example of clarity, however.  While returning that boolean expression is more concise, some people might prefer seeing it explicitly written out for ease of reading.

Comment: @BlackVegetable I understand the attempt, but I really like having only ONE return in a function. I would suggest `const bool ret = expression; return ret;` to keep clarity

Comment: @qdii I am intrigued by that style choice.  I haven't seen that before -- I will have to see if I like it.  Thank you.

Comment: @qdii I was only trying to make the code as clear as possible - I think that should be priority number 1 on a QA site.

Comment: Belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to keep a complete log of all previous calls; you just need to know how long the last x calls spanned.

```
const int x;
const int t;
bool have_we_made_enough_calls_lately() {
    static deque<int> times;
    times.push_back(current_time_in_msec());
    if (times.size() > x)
        times.pop_front();
    return times.back() - times.front() <= 1000 * t;
}
```

Edit: On checking other answers, I realise the question was ambiguous. It's not clear whether you want to return true if there were **at least** x calls (what I assumed) or **exactly** x calls (what others assumed).

Comment: what about a static array of size `x` and a `counter % x` ? then there would be no more allocation so no possible `std::bad_alloc` exception thrown

Comment: Sure, that would work if you really want to avoid allocation. Managing the array manually would be more complicated, you'd need to either move the whole array one cell down every time you drop an element, or keep track of the beginning and end points and allow for wraparound (effectively manually implementing a circular buffer). Simpler to use a deque that takes care of those details for you.

Comment: You can do both at "least x calls" and "exactly x calls" by keeping x+1 timestamps: "exactly x" is then "x is more recent than t and x+1 is not". FWIW. (Also, @qdii has a good point; %x is hardly difficult, and after the first x calls, the deque is fixed size.)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool calledXTimesInLastTSeconds() {
   static deque<long> last_calls;
   long time = currentTimeInMillis();

   // clear last calls
   long last_call_to_consider = time - 1000*t;
   while (last_calls.front() < last_call_to_consider)
      last_calls.pop_front()

  last_calls.push_back(time);
  return last_calls.size() == x;
}
```

Time complexity is amortized constant.

EDIT: This is how to check *exactly* x calls. Even if you can simply change this to at least x calls (by changing `==x` to `>=x`), but then the answer from Ross Smith is better since the memory usage has a constant upper limit.